# USB Boot only works intermittently with USD-SSD Adapter on Pi 3

Tags: usb, boot-issues

I have a Pi3 with a Sabrient USB-SSD Adapter. The disk works fine and can be mounted. However, when I try to use it as a boot disk, it works only intermittently.  Most of the time, there seems to be a timing problem with detecting the disk - in that case the blue LED on the adapter lights up briefly then nothing happens and the LED is off.

Some of the time - say on in fifteen times - the boot process detects the USB drive and boots up fine.

Any idea on how to make this detection more reliable ?

My Pi:  model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)

Many thanks

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all - Every Sabrent USB adapter I've ever tried simply fails to be a boot device - even on a PC it fails - what is the VID/PID of that particular adapter

Comment: Bus 001 Device 004: ID 152d:1561 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS561U two ports SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x152d JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp.
  idProduct          0x1561 JMS561U two ports SATA 6Gb/s bridge
  bcdDevice            2.04
  iManufacturer           1 SABRENT
  iProduct            2 SABRENT

Comment: BTW it boots fine on a Pi4, so it is definitely a firmware/software issue,

Comment: I wouldn't use sabrent products even if they paid me - so -

Comment: Ok, any suggestions for a better alternative based on your experience ?